# Add 10 months automatically to textbox2 based on user selected date in textbox1

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

I have 2 textboxes. 
In 1st text box user select the date by using calender control in asp.net. 
After adding the required date in textbox1, i wont to add the 10 months and display the date in textbox2 automatically. 
And which event i can use to add the date in textbox2 immediately after selecting the date in textbox1

Ex: `textbox1:19/12/2013 then after selecting this date, then textbox2 automatically fill with like textbox2:19/10/2014`

Please Help Me

Comment: when i select today date in textbox1 then i wont to add 10 monts to selected date in textbox1 and show it in textbox2 automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
DateTime add_Months = Convert.ToDateTime(textbox1.Text).AddMonths(10);
textbox2.Text = add_Months.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use html5

```
 <input type="date">
```

make it simple

For more info

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/common-microsyntaxes.html#dates-and-times